# Reuse virtual columns in MySQL SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to reuse a virtual column using by following SQL:

```sql
create view `thread_views` as
select
  `threads`.*,
  (
    select
      count(*)
    from
      `messages`
    where
      `threads`.`id` = `messages`.`thread_id`
      and `read_at` is null
      and `side` = 'client'
  ) as `unread_messages_client_count`,
  (
    select
      count(*)
    from
      `messages`
    where
      `threads`.`id` = `messages`.`thread_id`
      and `read_at` is null
      and `side` = 'admin'
  ) as `unread_messages_admin_count`,
  IF(`unread_messages_admin_count` = 0, 0, 1) AS has_unread_admin,
  IF(`unread_messages_client_count` = 0, 0, 1) AS has_unread_client,
  `users`.`first_name`,
  `users`.`last_name`,
  `users`.`email`,
  `users`.`ssn`,
  `users`.`mobile`
from
  `threads`
  inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `threads`.`user_id`
```

But it says:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'unread_messages_admin_count' in 'field list'...

The part with error is:

```sql
  IF(`unread_messages_admin_count` = 0, 0, 1) AS has_unread_admin,
  IF(`unread_messages_client_count` = 0, 0, 1) AS has_unread_client,
```

I want to reuse `unread_messages_admin_count` and `unread_messages_client_count` and make two boolean-like columns that indicate each one of mentioned columns having value more than 0 or not.

Comment: You can't refer to a column alias in the same query. Either repeat the expression, or use a subquery/CTE.